# How to remove status bar when TouchID Alert Appears?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, touch-id

I'm trying to hide the status bar throughout my entire app. However, the status bar appears when *TouchID* alert appears from within the app.

In my `AppDelegate.swift` file I have added the line:
`application.statusBarHidden = true`

This does not seem to cover the case when the *TouchID* function appears. Is there something specific for this case?

Comment: good question, I'm not sure it is possible...

Comment: When you implement an Apple framework such as Local Authentication framework, that contains an alert or an activity alert, you are actually handing over the focus of the phone to the system and therefore losing control of what happens.  The View that is on the screen would most likely have viewDidAppear on it again once the app has regained the focus.  Its strange that the system doesn't continue the style but there's nothing much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but for those who are still facing the same issue. Its not a Apple bug. You have to resolve it yourself.

I have check it with iOS 9, 10, 11 and its working fine. Just do the following steps:

- Open info.plist
- "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to NO
- "Status bar is initially hidden" set to YES

Its done :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an OS bug. We'll have to wait for Apple to fix it.

Meanwhile, there are always nasty workarounds.
Try hiding the status bar after 0.2 sec.

```
// Add this in the function that calls Touch ID
var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
  dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.hideStatusBar()
  })


// Add this function
func hideStatusBar () {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
}
```